# Mark a class deprecated with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm working on a codebase where a lot of the React components are being rewritten and replaced over time. Some of those components are "functional" and adding a deprecation tag to them triggers warnings and strikethrough styling in my IDE. But doing the same for a class doesn't trigger the same visual feedback.

Without the feedback from the IDE, and with the sparseness of the [JSDoc docs](http://jsdoc.app/tags-deprecated.html), I'm not sure I've got the syntax right or if the `@deprecated` tag applies to classes:

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
class OldAndBusted extends React.Component
```

Does the same syntax apply to classes? Can you mark those as *deprecated* in the same way as functions?

Comment: your syntax appears correct to me and is not currently displaying strikethrough hint in vscode v1.69

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the official documentation (http://jsdoc.app/tags-deprecated.html)

> The @deprecated tag marks a symbol in your code as being deprecated.

It is not said that the `@deprecated` tag is only for functions. It should be perfectly fine to tag a class as `@deprecated`.

The fact that your IDE understands it or not, ... depends on your IDE !

The jsDoc interpretation by IDEs is not complete, and a lot of things are not understood.